# why do I get and error when trying to use regex?

Tags: python, regex

using re.sub() for string objects, I receive TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

I am trying to clean up a bunch of tweets that I have downloaded and stored in a csv file. the csv file only contains two columns: a "No" column which shows the number of each tweet, and the "body." I am using re.sub() to remove all the "mentions" from the body of tweets. But the command returns an error. below is my code and error:

```py
# Convert to list
data = df.content.values.tolist()

# Remove mentions
data = [type(sent) for sent in data[:10]]
print(data)
data = [re.sub('\S*@\S*\s?', '', sent) for sent in data[:10]]
```

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

As you can see above, I double checked and made sure that the input to regex command is a string. However, the error I receive says otherwise

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bd1250ebb94b> in <module>
      6 data = [type(sent) for sent in data[:10]]
      7 print(data)
----> 8 data = [re.sub('\S*@\S*\s?', '', sent) for sent in data[:10]]
      9 

<ipython-input-11-bd1250ebb94b> in <listcomp>(.0)
      6 data = [type(sent) for sent in data[:10]]
      7 print(data)
----> 8 data = [re.sub('\S*@\S*\s?', '', sent) for sent in data[:10]]
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    193 
    194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Types aren't strings.

Comment: but they are! I double checked that

Comment: ...no, they really aren't. Even the type of a string isn't itself a string; instead, it's an instance of `type`, namely, `<type 'str'>`; its own type is `<type 'type'>`.

Comment: you are right. I had received the TypeError mistake and was trying to make sure the input is string. I forgot to remove that line, though, which blew up my code as you mentioned. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use `type` to check that your values are strings, but by reassigning the result back to `data`, you are performing the regex substitution on the types, when you want to apply it to the strings themselves.

Anyway, instead of using `re`, you can use `pandas`'s inbuilt functions:

```
df['content'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually types are of type "type" and not "str".

You can easily get the type's name by doing:

```py
data = [type(sent).__name__ for sent in data[:10]]
```

Comment: This produces strings, but almost certainly the wrong strings.

Comment: Hard to tell what the author is trying to do, since `data` gets replaced by the types right before the `print`.

Comment: It seems to be clear that reassignment was performed by mistake when attempting to verify the types.